# Create Block Diagram with two Blocks and rest of 0's

Tags: python, diagram

I need to make a block diagram where I have two diagonal blocks, with all other number zeros. I need it to be a 20x20 matrix.

What I have so far is

```
import numpy as np
T = 0.6
B = np.array([[T, np.sqrt(1-T)], [-np.sqrt(1-T), T]])

B_diag = np.kron(np.eye(10,dtype=int),B)
```

`

which gives a 20x20 matrix but with B on all diagonals. I am new to coding so unsure how to do this. Thanks for the help!

Required output:

```
|C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6|C7|C8|
|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|
|1|2|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|3|4|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|0|0|1|2|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|0|0|3|4|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
```

with 20 rows and 20 columns and where 1 = 4 = T, 2 = sqrt(T), 3 = -sqrt(T). The C's are just there for the formatting required by stack.

Comment: Can you include a table/image of the expected output? If not, can you include a small version of the expected output (e.g. 5x5)?

Comment: Added in the output @Robson

Comment: Can you describe the equation for the 2x2 sub-block? I'm a bit confused by *1 = 4 = T, 2 = sqrt(T), 3 = -sqrt(T)*

Comment: @IanGraham Hi, I'm new to stack so was struggling to format the table. T is a variable, so in the list replace the numbers 1 and 4 with T, and 2 with sqrt(T) and 3 with -sqrt(T), and that is the out put I want .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to splice the 4x4 array into a larger 20x20 array of zeros.

```py
import numpy as np
T = 0.6
B = np.array([[T, np.sqrt(1-T)], [-np.sqrt(1-T), T]])

B_diag = np.kron(np.eye(2,dtype=int),B)

M = np.zeros((20,20))

M[:4, :4] = B_diag

print(M)
```

And you get the expected output in the first 5x5 block

```
[[ 0.6         0.63245553  0.          0.          0.        ]
 [-0.63245553  0.6        -0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.6         0.63245553  0.        ]
 [-0.          0.         -0.63245553  0.6         0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]
```

Comment: Ah ok, so it is quite simple then! Thankyou, I will do that!

Comment: Yup! Yea so just nail down your formula for that 2x2 piece, and the rest is easy!

Comment: Also, not to pry, would you mind accepting the answer? :) Thanks!